# Laravel php artisan serve logs stored and start artisan serve automatically

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

id like to know :

1. Where Laravel `php artisan serve` command  logs stored ?
2. How to automatically start `php artisan serve` when sever (Apache) starts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the first question

> Where Laravel php artisan serve command logs stored ?

Laravel server logs are stored in `storage/logs` folder ,which contains files for the server logs

To the second question

> How to automatically start php artisan serve when sever (Apache) starts ?

If you need to automatically ,A very simple way to do this would be to use use laravel scheduling Artisan Commands using cron

1. Ensure cron is installed `yum install vixie-cron` (assuming you use centos). Start it with `service crond start`
2. Add laravel Schedule object `vi /etc/crontab` and add  `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1` ,to the cron schedule file .
3. Go to app/Console/Kernel.php file and add `$schedule->command('foo')->withoutOverlapping();` where foo is the artisan command you would like to run in this case `serve` , so it should be `$schedule->command('serve')->withoutOverlapping();`
4. Restart cron deamon with `service crond restart`.

See this related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096590/1226748

Answer (score 6):

1. Laravel logs are stored at storage/logs
2. You don't need `artisan serve`, if you have Apache handling your HTTP traffic.

Comment: acctually am developing an angular app with integration to  laravel , and angular app run on port 8080 , which requires me have set server to run on port 8080 which have done , but the app will  not run untill i run `php artisan serve` to run on that port any suggestion is highly recommended .

Comment: You mean you want Laravel on different port than angular? Check out supervisord.

Comment: Here you go http://supervisord.org; however, I still think you can handle by Apache, for example host Laravel on subdomain, like api.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend NOT using artisan's server in production like EVER, it's for testing only. -- You would be WAY better off to use nginx as a reverse proxy and you can set whatever port you want that way, and have your angular app still connect to it.

Comment: Tried this on apache but apprently does not work until artisan (php server ) is started !